# How can I compare a string with smaller and smaller parts of another string?

Tags: java, compare

I have a multipart string like this:

```
String Y = "part1 part2 part3 part4"; // This is only an example value
```

I want to write a function that compares the complete string Y with another strin, X. (Normally I will compare it with a list.) If the strings are not equal, then `part1 part2 part3` should be compared with X. If they are not equal, X should be compared with `part1 part2`, and then finally with just `part1`.

I can use `split(" ")` to break the string up. I don't know the number of chunks in the string. How can I write this comparison method?

Comment: An example would clarify a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an algorithm like this:

```
boolean foundMatch = false;
while(!foundMatch) {
    foundMatch = Y.equals(X);
    if(foundMatch) {
        break;
    }
    else {
        Y = Y.useSplitToRemoveLastPart();
        if(Y.equals("")) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

That's only pseudocode, of course. It seemed like you had a general idea how to do each of these individual parts. If you need more guidance, just let me know.

EDIT:
Assuming your strings will always be space-delimited like they are in your example, you could do something like this:

```
String userSplitToRemoveLastPart(String Y) {
    // Find the last space
    int lastSpace = Y.lastIndexOf(" ");

    // Return only the part of the string that comes before the last space
    return Y.substring(0, lastSpace);
}
```

I haven't tested this, and it may **not** be the most efficient way to perform the split, but I think the algorithm is clear.

Comment: Can you be more clear about what goes inside useSplitToRemoveLastPart()

Comment: @Praneel, I updated. Ended up not using `split()` at all because I thought of a shorter way.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should get you started:

```
class SpecialComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {

        // Get parts to compare
        String[] words1 = o1.split(" ");
        String[] words2 = o2.split(" ");

        // Reverse arrays to start with the last word first.
        Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(words1));
        Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(words2));

        int n = Math.min(words1.length, words2.length);

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int result = words1[n].compareTo(words2[i]);

            if (result != 0)     // not equal, differing words found.
                return result;
        }

        // Deal with the situation in which the strings are of different length.
        // ...

        // They're equal.
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused by your expected outcome. The goal seems to be to simply count partial matches, which this accomplishes:

```
public boolean foo(final String str1, final String str2) {
    return Pattern.matches(" " + str1 + " (.*)", " " + str2 + " ");
}
```

Some tests:

```
String target = "part1 part2 part3 part4";
foo("part1 part2 part3 part4", target); // true
foo("part1 part2 part3", target); // true
foo("part1 part2", target); // true
foo("part1", target); // true
foo("part1 part3", target)); // false
```

Comment: @Lord Torgamus - No, it won't, because `matches` "attempts to match the entire input sequence against the pattern."

Comment: Right you are. I'm not so sharp on regexes at the moment, it seems. Deleting my comment and upvoting you.

Comment: @Lord - That behavior always makes me think twice, since I don't imagine my regexes to always have implict `^` and `$`